# Save kubectl command output in variable in Bashscript

Tags: bash, shell, kubectl

Just want to save the output from a kubectl command in a variable in a Bash script.

For example: command `kubectl get all -n mattermost` outputs `No resources found in mattermost namespace.`

```sh
foo=$(kubectl get all -n mattermost)

while [ "$foo" = "No resources found in mattermost namespace." ]
do
  echo "yay"
done
```

Unfortunately the output won't save in the variable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There  are two problems with your script...

1. The problem you described is because its an error message you try to catch but you catch normal massages only. Bash and other Shells use ***stdin*** ***stdout*** and ***stderr*** for messaging. With your command the variable will catch *stdout* only.

- 2 = stderr
- 1 = stdout
- 0 = stdin
- & = means some like add this to that
- < > = where to go with stdxxx

It should be more like ...

```
foo=$(ANY COMMAND 2>&1)
```

2. When you run the script it will create that variable first and after that the loop will be endless, cause there are no changes to that variable.
   Instead you could get rid of that variabe and put it in your loop.

```
while [ "$(kubectl get all -n mattermost 2>&1)" = "No resources found in mattermost namespace." ]; do
echo "Hello World"
done
```

This way your loop will stop when ***stderr*** or ***stdout*** will change. There is also the possibility to stop the loop with a `break` or stop the script with `return` or `exit` (depending on how you will run that script).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

For a message like "No resources found ....", it is printing in stderr. To rectify this, you can modify your line to

```
foo=$(kubectl get all -n mattermost 2>&1)
```